# Unable to map a JSON field with Hyphen to the Java Object field

Tags: java, json, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

The Java POJO is like this:

```
import javax.validation.Valid;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;


 Class MyClass{

 @JsonProperty(value = "config-meta-info")
 @Valid
 private ConfigMetaInformation configMetaInfo;

 @JsonProperty(value = "name")
 @Valid
 private String name;

public MyClass(){}

public MyClass(String name,ConfigMetaInformation  configMetaInfo){
this.name=name;
this.configMetaInfo=configMetaInfo;
}

@JsonProperty("name")
public String getName() {
return name;
}

@JsonProperty("name")
public void setName(String name) {
this.name = name;
}

 @JsonProperty("config-meta-info")
public ConfigMetaInformation getConfigMetaInfo() {
return configMetaInfo;
}

@JsonProperty("config-meta-info")
public void setConfigMetaInfo(ConfigMetaInformation configMetaInfo) {
this.configMetaInfo= configMetaInfo;
}

}
```

I am Using the JSON as below:

```
{
  "name":"abc",
 "config-meta-info":"someInfo" 
}
```

But when I try to get the Data from the MongoDB document , I am seeing the config-meta-info as null.
Am I missing anything to handle this kebab-case key?

Comment: Can you show what the class `ConfigMetaInformation` is? I cannot see there is something special in your JSON string, so why not just declare `configMetaInfo` as a string just like `name`?

Comment: Yes, only the camelCase worked finally.

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong in the case of MongoDB but in other JSON based databases, they don't allow hyphenation in the field/key, underscores are usually preferred. Instead of `config-meta-info`, try `config_meta_info`.

Comment: @BindumaliniKK Okay, when checking the MongoDB documentation for POJO I notice that they use ```@BsonProperty``` instead of ```@JsonProperty```. Also when checking an online JSON validator it is required that you enclose the keys in the JSON in quotations, like ```"name"``` and ```"config-meta-info"```

Answer (score 0):

The structure which you showed:

```
{
  name:"abc",
  config-meta-info:"someInfo" 
}
```

is not a JSON.
Specification [RFC-8259](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259) defines all types (6) but what is `name` or `config-meta-info`? It can be JavaScript, but not a JSON.

The proper JSON:

```
{
  "name":"abc",
  "config-meta-info":"someInfo" 
}
```

And you can use hyphen without limitations.